# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileEncryptionInfoBuilder

Tags: java, excel, encryption, apache-poi

I am using Apache Poi.3.10-FINAL jar for Generating Excel Sheet.I tried for Password Protection  using this below code.I getting Error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileEncryptionInfoBuilder
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:135)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:91)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:80)
at com.tcs.ServiceCatalog.Common.main(Common.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileEncryptionInfoBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.getBuilder(EncryptionInfo.java:150)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:133)
... 3 more
```

Code: Taken from the [link.](http://www.quicklyjava.com/create-password-protected-excel-using-apache-poi/)

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs, EncryptionMode.agile);

    Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
    enc.confirmPassword("s3cr3t");

    OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File("c:/test/excel.xlsx"), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
    OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
    opc.save(os);
    opc.close();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/test/excel.xlsx");
    fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
    fos.close();
```

I tried searching for the missing class `org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileEncryptionInfoBuilder` but couldn't find it.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need `poi-ooxml-3.10.FINAL`. Download and add it to your classpath.

Comment: @GGG also `poi-ooxml-3.10.FINAL` (without schemas)?

Comment: Yes `poi-ooxml-3.10.FINAL` and `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar` both.